# ¿Como ejecutar funcion en un intervalo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, hilos

Estoy intentando ejecutar una función en segundo plano cada 5 segundos en la que compruebe los datos de un objeto y lo modifique.

He encontrado esta forma (ver código) pero no consigo que se ejecute cuando despliego el servidor de Django.

### Codigo

```
import threading

def hilo_promo(f_stop):
    print('se ejecuta hilo')
    promocion = Promocion.objects.get(id=1)
    if promocion.fecha_fin.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') <= hoy and promocion.activo == True:
        promocion.activo = False
        promocion.save()
    if not f_stop.is_set():
        threading.Timer(5, hilo_promo, [f_stop]).start()
    print(promocion.activo)

f_stop = threading.Event()
hilo_promo(f_stop)
```

Comment: Has leído acerca de Celery?